# Check if Previous post item has a certain Wordpress post format

Tags: php, wordpress, get, echo, post-format

I'm using the WP post formats in my theme, and I want to echo parts of the previous posts in my single-post page. Echoing it works fine, however I only want previous posts from a specific post-format to show. I tried using an `if` statement with the `has_post_format()` function, but it wouldn't work:

php:

```
$prev_post = get_previous_post();

$prev_post_id = $prev_post->ID;

$prev_post_title = $prev_post->post_title;

function prev_post_item($object) {  
    if (!has_post_format('gallery', $prev_post_id)) {
        echo $object;
    }
}
```

html:

```
<h2><?php prev_post_item($prev_post_title); ?></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options

```
<h2>
    <?php
        $prev_post = get_previous_post();
        $prev_post_id = $prev_post->ID;
        if ( ! has_post_format('gallery', $prev_post_id ) ) {
            echo 'Is not a gallery'
        }
     ?>
</h2>
```

or in a function

```
function your_prev_post_item() {  
    $prev_post = get_previous_post();
    $prev_post_id = $prev_post->ID;
    if (!has_post_format('gallery', $prev_post_id)) {
        echo 'Is not a gallery'
    }
}
```

then the HTML

```
<h2><?php your_prev_post_item(); ?></h2>
```

Comment: Ah, I need the variables inside the function?